# How to setup sms and othe native permission in Ionic project?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, permissions, sms

I have developed one android application using ionic. I have used plugin to read sms for OTP. It works fine if I give SMS permission from application settings after installation. But it does not ask for permission if permission not given. So in the case of new installation application does not check SMS due to lack of SMS permission.

I would like to know if there any way to ask permission at the time of installation or while using the services (Android 6.0+).

Answer (score 0):

Write this code while using service for read sms permission at runtime in marshmallow.

`if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
  // request for permission
  requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},request_code);`

and override this method in your activty call after grant permission

```
     @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case request_code: {
            // TODO: after granted permission you write your code
            return;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this code should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.

Comment: I need a code that works with ionic or apache cordova. As I already mentioned. My application is developed using ionic.